# What am I doing wrong, or is it my device?

Tags: help, troubleshooting, mobile

Use a Motorola Moto-E for my device. Successfully downloaded Tor, Orweb, and Duck Duck Goose browser, however, even though Tor says it's active, when I check any browser (DDG, Chrome, Google) the device says I am configured for Tor, gives me an apparent address, then says my browser isn't on For and I should download the app (again?), which doesn't work. Reload doesn't fix it, either.

Comment: What happens when you start the Orweb-app?

Comment: I am having problems with orweb, it was working fine but my system updated on my hudl2 tablet to lollypop and since the update when I start orweb it detects orbot is not running and starts it, then orweb says it is not connecting through the Tor network although orbot reports it is working. I will uninstall and reinstall orweb to see if that helps. **Conclusion Edit** I updated orweb to the latest version from play store and it said it could fix problems with android 5 (Lollypop) and it worked.
Everything is working ok now

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use Orweb, or download Orfox and run that as your browser. No need for chrome or duckduckgo browser at this point, those would be better suited for your clearnet activity. I'm sure you could setup these to route through tor but its much easier/safer to use Orfox or Orweb which come pre-configured with privacy in mind and automatically route through Tor.

Orfox is actually from the Tor Project so I would recommend using it over Orweb.

Orfox:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.orfox&hl=en